# How to Pass a Partial View To Layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

This is a sanity check on my approach to passing a partial view to the layout header.

In my layout, I have a location for the navigation buttons I want to display for each page.

Using a view model for that layout, I can pass a string of data to the layout and have it displayed at that location, no problem.

I am currently building the navigation I want to display in a partial view and then render it to a string and pass it into the layout via the layout view model and everything works fine.

Is this a common approach to passing a partial view to the layout or is there a better approach?

As I said, this is working perfectly fine but it seems a bit hackish to render html to pass through a string. It would be nice to be able to natively pass a partial view and have it render in the layout rather then passing the HTML, if that is possible.

Thank you for your thoughts as suggestions.

Earl

Comment: No its not. Why are you not just using `Html.Partial("...")` in the layout, or if you need to call a controller method to perform some logic, then `Html.Action(...)`

Comment: Just use @Html.Partial if you're going to do it that way...

Comment: What is the reason for passing part of the page as html string via model? Can't you just use `Html.Partial()` in your layout page to render it?

Comment: Everyone, thank you for your help. Yes, this is perfect and I think it will work. I do need to call the partial view action so I need to use @html.Action. My only issue is that each of my partial view actions is passed a different data model. I could make a super model that includes everything and pass that in to all of the partial view actions I want to render in the layout, but that seems very clumsy. How would pass in the exact data model for each partial view action method to the layout html.action helper using this technique? Thank you.

Comment: After thinking about it for a few minutes, Its possible that I could use a base interface that all of the partial view action method data models inherit from. This base interface does not need any properties of its own but is simply used as a carrier to allow me to pass different models to the controller action and then have them cast back to there original type in the receiving partial view action itself. Just a thought.

Comment: The model for an action method can not be an interface so what I did was create a class with an interface property and used that to pass different models to the partial views depending on what they needed. This as worked out very well and provided very flexible placeholders for the partial view content rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the name (or an instance of) the partial view, and let it render inline (so there's no intermediate string allocation).

You should use `ViewData` for one-way (controller-to-view) data exchange instead of the `ViewModel` (which should be used for two-way data, in my opinion).

Like so:

```
View.cshtml

@model SomeViewModel
@{
    Layout = "Layout.cshtml";

    if( userIsAdmin ) {
        this.ViewData["NavigationPartialName"] = "AdminLinks";
    }
    else {
        this.ViewData["NavigationPartialName"] = "NormalLinks";
    }
}
```

Layout.cshtml:

```
<nav>
    @{ Html.RenderPartial( this.ViewData["NavigationPartialName"] ); }
</nav>
```

(Note that `Html.RenderPartial` is generally better than `Html.Partial` because it writes directly to the parent output stream or buffer, whereas `Html.Partial` simply returns an `MvcHtmlString` which is inefficient unless you really need an intermediate string. Because `RenderPartial` is a `void` method you need to wrap it in `@{  }` instead of the more succinct `@()` which requires a return value).

But this can be simplified, the what-partial-to-display logic can exist entirely in the Layout file:

```
@{
    Boolean userIsAdmin = this.ViewData["UserIsAdmin"];
}

<nav>
    @{ Html.RenderPartial( userIsAdmin ? "AdminLinks" : "NormalLinks" ); }
</nav>
```

And you can set `this.ViewData["UserIsAdmin"]` in your controller:

```
class BaseController : Controller {

    protected override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext) {

        this.ViewData["UserIsAdmin"] = this.User.IsInRole("Administrator");
    }
}
```

You can also use strongly-typed ViewData subclasses if you don't like using dictionaries for ViewData, you could also store the `"UserIsAdmin"` key string as a global const too.

Comment: Dai, thank you for your explanation. I can work with a version of this. Very helpful!!!